# SMS Inbox issue on TouchWiz

Tags: android, sms

I am writing an Android app that will display the number of messages sent by each of the user's contacts. I have tested the app on my Nexus S (Android 4.1.2) and it is working as expected. Now, the other day I was testing the same application on a Galaxy S Duos (Android 4.0.1) and I am not able to see the contact details. The code I have used is given below.

```
public static String    SMS_URI_INBOX   = "content://sms/inbox";
Uri parsedUri = Uri.parse(SMS_URI_INBOX);
String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "address", "person" };
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(parsedUri, projection, null, null, null);

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    String person;
    int personIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("person");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        do {
            // The person will be the foreign key from the Contacts table
            person = cursor.getString(personIndex);

            if (person != null) {
                // Add this person to a list
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
```

On a Samsung device running TouchWiz, at the line `person = cursor.getString(personIndex);`, I seem to be getting the value for `person` as null.

I tried printing out all the values of the cursor (30 columns) and couldn't find a different  column name that suits this value. I know a message can be mapped to a contact as the Messaging app proves it.

Have anyone faced a similar issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some Android phones the person column is deprecated. So you should not rely on this column. Not only samsung all sony devices running 4.1.2 and later will give you null value.

Comment: OK, but what alternative is there in such cases. The Message applications prove that there is a way to map a message with a contact. Thanks for this info, since I was solely testing on Nexus devices, I had never come across this issue before.

Comment: what do you want to get from sms database? only person column?

Comment: Yes, so that I can count the number of messages received from this contact. Its working for Nexus Devices.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is also possible with address column only. Just calculate how many time a number is there in address column, similar to `group by` query in database.

Comment: in case a contact has more than 1 number (and has sent messages from each), this approach won't work.

Comment: You can easily found if the contact has more than one number. using `PhoneLookUp` query, and also you can compare contact names.

Comment: @silverback , rather than iterating over each and every sms and doing a query to find out who's involved, use the `content://sms/conversations` uri and for each conversation find out who's involved, then for each conversation count the number of smses in the inbox. This should be much faster than going over thousands of messages.

Comment: @vikki I don't get your idea. When a person send SMS from different numbers then new conversation will be started for each phone number and also different conversations get different thread id.

Comment: @sunny yes, but you can determine who owns the phone number right? The algorithm would look something like this, open conversation, find out who's number we are working with in this conversation, now that you know the person(let's call him person x), count the number of messages in the inbox, add this count to person x's total count. Repeat this for all conversations.

Comment: @sunny Every time you encounter a number belonging to person x you are going to increment his count. Note that if you choose to iterate over each sms, you'd be doing something quite close to this only that you'll be doing more of it. Since android has already grouped these messages for you by phone number you only need to work with the group and not each and every member of the group.